# Marklogic - Xpath using get attribute value

Tags: xpath, marklogic

I have displayed sample Xml data in below ,  If title lang ="it" then i want to get  category attribute value ?

```
<book category="CLASSICS">
  <title lang="it">Purgatorio</title>
  <author>Dante Alighieri</author>
  <year>1308</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"If `title` `lang ="it"` then i want to get `category` attribute value ?"*

The XPath should be straightforward :

```
//book[title/@lang='it']/@category
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use following XPATH Expression.
`doc("XML-URI")/book[title/@lang/string() eq "it"]/@category`